# Make column environment ignore frame margins in beamer

Tags: beamer, multicolumn

I'd like to define the exact horizontal position and width of columns using [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer).

For example:

1. Column which starts at `.05\paperwidth` and is `.55\paperwidth` wide
2. Column which starts at `.60\paperwidth` and is `.30\paperwidth` wide

So my thought was to set the **totalwidth of all columns** to the **paperwidth**

```
totalwidth=\paperwidth
```

and use **4 columns instead of 2** and leave the first and last unused, just to produce the desired gaps. But it is not working as the margins are considered, which is weird, because with no width set the margins are ignored also.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamersetrightmargin{0.1\paperwidth}
\beamersetleftmargin{0.1\paperwidth}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{columns}[totalwidth=\paperwidth]

\column{.05\paperwidth}
\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\strut x}
\column{.55\paperwidth}
\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\strut one}
\column{.3\paperwidth}
\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\strut two}
\column{.1\paperwidth}
\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\strut x}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

producing
[image]

I tried to wrap

```
{\beamersetleftmargin{0pt}
\column{.05\paperwidth}
...
}
```

around my columns which did not work. And this solution does not "feel" right.

**How can I make it work? Any alternative approaches?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason **not assigning any width** is the solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamersetrightmargin{0.1\paperwidth}
\beamersetleftmargin{0.1\paperwidth}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{columns}

\column{.05\paperwidth}
\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\strut x}
\column{.55\paperwidth}
\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\strut one}
\column{.3\paperwidth}
\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\strut two}
\column{.1\paperwidth}
\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\strut x}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]